# PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process help me

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to do a data clean but I'm not able to save my file cause the terminal says "PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". I've already tried everything and I really need help on this.
There's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook

datasetbase = "database/2000.xls"

tabelabase = pd.read_excel(datasetbase)
colunascertas = tabelabase.columns

ntabela = 2002
atual = "database/"
atual += (str(ntabela)+".xlsx")
            
planilha = load_workbook(atual)
aba_ativa = planilha[str(ntabela)]

tabelaatual = pd.read_excel(atual)
print("lidos")

for colunaerrada in tabelaatual:
    if colunaerrada not in colunascertas:
        print("diferente encontrada!")
        index = tabelaatual.columns.get_loc(colunaerrada)
        aba_ativa.delete_cols(index, 1)
        print("Removida")
print("sucesso!")
planilha.save('database/2002.xlsx')
print("Finalizado ",ntabela)
```

and There's the console message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 110, in get_column_letter
    return _STRING_COL_CACHE[idx]
KeyError: 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\Desktop\Estudo\Python\DataScience\Tennis\tratamento.py", line 26, in <module>
    planilha.save('database/2002.xlsx')
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\workbook.py", line 386, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 294, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 77, in write_data
    self._write_worksheets()
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 215, in _write_worksheets
    self.write_worksheet(ws)
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\writer\excel.py", line 200, in write_worksheet
    writer.write()
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 358, in write
    self.write_top()
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 100, in write_top
    self.write_dimensions()
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 70, in write_dimensions
    dim = SheetDimension(ref())
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 401, in calculate_dimension       
    return f"{get_column_letter(min_col)}{min_row}:{get_column_letter(max_col)}{max_row}"
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\utils\cell.py", line 112, in get_column_letter
    raise ValueError("Invalid column index {0}".format(idx))
ValueError: Invalid column index 0
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 32, in _openpyxl_shutdown
    os.remove(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo: 'C:\\Users\\MEUCOM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\openpyxl.7xu0910d'
Exception ignored in: <generator object WorksheetWriter.get_stream at 0x000001F2300D0580>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\_writer.py", line 300, in get_stream
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 124, in __exit__
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 50, in element
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile\xmlfile.py", line 77, in _write_element
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 1109, in tostring
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 732, in write
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 117, in __enter__
  File "C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 801, in _get_writer
LookupError: unknown encoding: us-ascii
```

I've already tried to check the numbers of columns, the name of the new file,... but nothing changed.

Comment: The title is a different error the one in the traceback. Which is the problem?

Comment: That's cause I'm Brazilian, and translating the title to portuguese, it becomes "PermissionError: [WinError 32] O arquivo já está sendo usado por outro processo:"

Comment: The file is locked: do you have it open in Excel?